# Redirect from method to another View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have controller:

```
void user()
{
    var user = (from ....);
    if(user !=null)
    {
        ......
    }
    else
      RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

public ActionResult xyz()
{
    user();

    return View();
}
```

If user is null is make

> RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

but it no redirect but return View in xyz() method. How make redirect who will go to another View. And stop making xyz() method. It will be very useful if I mustn't change something in xyz method.

Comment: You need to actually RETURN the RedirectToActionResult in order to cause a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[NonAction]
ActionResult user()
{
    var user = (from ....);
    if(user !=null)
    {
        ......
        return null;
    }
    else
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

public ActionResult xyz()
{
    var userAction = user();
    if (userAction != null) return userAction;

    return View();
}
```